# how to use YOLOv5 object detection model to train a single class(e.g. bird) dataset?

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, loss-function, yolov5

1.I modified the data.yaml and yolov5.yaml files.
nc:1
class:bird.

2.after training from scratch about 10 epochs, i found that the class loss is o in every epoch.

I don't know which steps I might have missed, or if it could be due to an error in the class loss function. The original yolov5 uses the BCE loss function, but can this loss function be used for a dataset with only one class? Can you help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: This github issue contains relevant info
https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/726

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.